# If $f: A \rightarrow B$ and $g: B \rightarrow C$, is $(g \circ f)^{-1}(C) = f^{-1}(B)$?

Tags: functions, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

Let $f: A \rightarrow B$ and $g: B \rightarrow C$. I have a question that is asking me to come up with and prove some theorems about the images and inverse images of sets under $g \circ f$. This is a theorem and proof that I have so far (sorry, I'm not great at writing proofs):

**Theorem:** Suppose $f: A \rightarrow B$ and $g: B \rightarrow C$. Then $(g \circ f)^{-1}(C) = f^{-1}(B)$.

$(\subseteq)$ Suppose $x \in (g \circ f)^{-1}(C)$. This implies that $x \in A$. Since $x \in A$ and $f: A \rightarrow B$ is a function, then $f(x) \in B$. Thus, since $x \in A$ and $f(x) \in B$, it follows that $x \in f^{-1}(B)$.

$(\supseteq)$ Suppose $x \in f^{-1}(B)$. This implies that $x \in A$ and $f(x) \in B$. Since $f(x) \in B$ and $g: B \rightarrow C$ is a function, then $g(f(x)) \in C$. Thus, since $x \in A$ and $g(f(x))=(g \circ f)(x) \in C$, it follows that $x \in (g \circ f)^{-1}(C)$.

Is this a valid theorem and proof, or is this not always true? I'm having trouble trying to come up with a counterexample.

Comment: By definition $(g \circ f)^{-1}(C) =A$ and $f^{-1}(B) =A$.

Comment: @N.S.: They do not just follow by definition.

Comment: @CliveNewstead If $h :X \to Y$ then by definition $$h^{-1}(Y)=\{x \in X :h(x) \in Y\}=X$$ with the last equality being obvious (i.e. for all $x \in X$ we automatically have $h(x) \in Y$).

Comment: @N.S.: I didn't say it wasn't obvious, I just said it wasn't by definition! Obvious facts still require some proof at this microscopic level.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is valid. However, it would be easier to prove that if $h : X \to Y$ is any function then $h^{-1}(Y) = X$. It then follows that $(g \circ f)^{-1}(C) = f^{-1}(B)$ simply because $g \circ f$ and $f$ have the same domain!

Answer (score -1):

Provided that $f,g$ are both $1-1$ and unto, you can also work this out by first showing that $$(g \circ f)^{-1}(x)=f^{-1}\circ g^{-1}(x).$$
Then it follows that $$(g\circ f)^{-1}(C)=f^{-1}(g^{-1}(C))=f^{-1}(B) $$

Comment: I don't think this answers the question—the function in the question need not be bijective, and you seem to be applying an inverse function to an element, rather than applying the inverse image operator to a subset.

Comment: Note that the original question does not contain your assumptions.